# How to hide submenu with addEventListener by clicking anywhere in webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to code toggle function but i can't think of it, my submenu can show and hide by clicking at Topics.

But i also want submenu to hide by clicking anywhere in webpage.

I'm very new to javacsript, i wish i could have some simple code or idea that easily for me to understand. If any one can give me some advices i would very appreciate it thank you.

(Just only javascript not Jquery)

```js
var toggleMenu = (function () {
    var mainTopics = document.getElementById("maintopics");

    mainTopics.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mainTopics.classList.toggle("show");
    });

    return {
        toggleMenu: toggleMenu()
    }
})();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}

/*main-menu*/
#mainmenu {
    position: relative;
}

#mainmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/*sub-topics*/
#subtopics {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#maintopics.show #subtopics {
    display: block;
}

#maintopics.hide #subtopics {
    display: none;
}


#subtopics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#subtopics li {
    display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}

/*columns*/
#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

/*hover underline*/
#mainmenu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li id="maintopics"><a href="">Topics</a>
                <div id="subtopics">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Test1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: addEventListener to document or body to hide menu

Comment: @JanakaDissanayake I did as you said but it didn't work. Is there others method to do it ?

Comment: One friendly suggestion: If don't have much experience with JavaScript then I suggest to research web on "capturing (mouse) events with JavaScript" and try to understand what propagation and event bubbling are. Any of solutions that people eventually post here may be hard to understand if you don't know how events work in JavaScript.

Comment: have a look on this https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 1):

How about just using CSS?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  color: black;
}


/*main-menu*/

#mainmenu {
  position: relative;
}

#mainmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}


/*sub-topics*/

#subtopics {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  /*margin-top: 10px;*/
  top: 41px;
  width: 100%;
  /*left: 0;*/
}

#maintopics.show #subtopics {
  display: block;
}

#subtopics ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#subtopics li {
  display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
  text-align: left;
}


/*columns*/

#column1,
#column2,
#column3 {
  position: relative;
  /*float: left;
  left: 125px;*/
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}


/*hover underline*/

#mainmenu li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#mainmenu li:hover #subtopics {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Logo</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li id="maintopics"><a href="">Topics</a>
        <div id="subtopics">
          <div id="column1" class="columns">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Test1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Test2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Test3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. but i know how to hover it, i only just want with addEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a method say `toggleHtml();`.
2) Put your logic in it.
3) call it from html body tag like below.

```
<body onClick="toggleHtml();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var toggleMenu = (function () {
    var mainTopics = document.getElementById("maintopics");

    mainTopics.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mainTopics.classList.toggle("show");
    });

     document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mainTopics.classList.toggle("hide");
    });
    
})();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}

/*main-menu*/
#mainmenu {
    position: relative;
}

#mainmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/*sub-topics*/
#subtopics {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#maintopics.show #subtopics {
    display: block;
}

#maintopics.hide #subtopics {
    display: none;
}


#subtopics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#subtopics li {
    display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}

/*columns*/
#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

/*hover underline*/
#mainmenu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=''>Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>Home</a></li>
            <li id="maintopics"><a href=''>Topics</a>
                <div id="subtopics">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Test1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```